Why does "SettingWithCopyWarning" get raised (seemingly) inconsistently?
Setup
We first import pandas and numpy and then create a 5000 rows x 10 columns pd.DataFrame called df
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate non-trivial df
data = np.random.rand(5000, 10)
column_names = [f'col_{i}' for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)

Get SettingWithCopyWarning warning
We then take df and select 2 columns and add to them a new column with the static value 10
foo = df
print(f"foo has type {type(foo)}\n")
bar = foo[["col_0", "col_1"]]
bar["new"] = 10
print(f"After modification bar has {type(bar)}\n\nbar is:\n{bar}")

This gives the output
foo has type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

After modification bar has <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

bar is:
         col_0     col_1  new
0     0.837911  0.715060   10
...        ...       ...  ...
4999  0.684007  0.176949   10

[5000 rows x 3 columns]
C:\Users\vents\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5824\1295636698.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  bar["new"] = 10

Notice the warning at the bottom
Do the same to a different df, but don't get SettingWithCopyWarning
Now we do the same as above, but set foo to a trivial table
foo = pd.DataFrame([["x",20.2,30], ["y",80,70]], columns=["col_0", "col_1", "col_2"])
print(f"foo has type {type(foo)}\n")
bar = foo[["col_0", "col_1"]]
bar["new"] = 10
print(f"After modification bar has {type(bar)}\n\nbar is:\n{bar}")

This now gives the output
foo has type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

After modification bar has <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

bar is:
  col_0  col_1  new
0     x   20.2   10
1     y   80.0   10

We have no warning.
My explanation(?) and thoughts
As far as I understand, SettingWithCopyWarning means that there is uncertainty around whether the table is a copy or a view. So maybe pandas has some optimization logic where if the table is small it just gives you a copy because, "oh what the hell, just save them the headache; their table is tiny, we'll just make a copy for them"??? But then for a bigger table it doesn't want to waste RAM making a copy so it requires users to be smarter?
That's my best guess.
I'm just not happy with taking the generic advice of, "Oh, just use foo.loc[:, ["col_0", "col_1"] or foo[["col_0", "col_1"]].copy() and you won't get the error", because I am not sure I fully understand the problem...
Like what other parts of my code are bad, but I'm getting (un)lucky to not getting the warning?
From what I've seen online most SettingWithCopyWarnings often get thrown if you take a subset of your data that has a different type to your original table and then try to do stuff to it (e.g. foo[0]["col_0"], which first takes the series foo[0] and then from that gives you the column col_0).
